# Why can't NetBeans connect to MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql

I have a MySQL database called employee.
I want to connect to this database using NetBeans.

I get the following exception:

> java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot load connection class because of underlying exception: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.WrongArgumentException: Failed to parse the host:port pair 'localhost:3306:employee'.

My code is:

```
try {
           Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
       } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
        }
  
    try {
        String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306:employee";
    String userName = "root";
    String password = "admin";
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, userName, password);
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        String query = "INSERT INTO user Email, FirstName, LastName) VALUES  ('xx@gmail.com', 'Andrea', 'Stee');";
        int rowCount = statement.executeUpdate(query);
        
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(UserDB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Any suggestion to correct this error?
Do I need to add the connector somewhere in my application web?

Comment: Did you read the error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the url should be updated like this.

```
String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee";
```

Comment: Reference for further reading: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-jdbc-url-format.html